# Want to get executed query with their users log in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

Yesterday one of my team members has truncated a few tables, but who it was is still a mystery.

Can I have user based query log with the timing of execution? Or something where I can enable that functionality in future??

Currently, I am using SQL Server 2017 on Linux.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: SQL Server DLL Trigger link https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2085/sql-server-ddl-triggers-to-track-all-database-changes/

Comment: You should ask who did it. Second if user has enough privileges he could disable trigger/clear log table after truncating. And finally I would probably use audit [How to capture Delete and Truncate T-SQL using Database Audit Specification](https://sqlship.wordpress.com/2011/06/30/how-to-capture-delete-and-truncate-t-sql-using-database-audit-specification/)

Answer (score 1):

logged users:

```
select * from master..syslogins
```

Actions on tables:

db -> Reports -> Standard Reports -> Schema Changes History

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But actually, those tables have already modified in between many times. That is why I want to go to the specific query on specific timing.